# How can I edit the wp_parse_auth_cookie function from the pluggable file in my functions?

Tags: functions, pluggable

I need to modify that function to decrypt the username that I have encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a [pluggable function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), and surrounded by an `if` statement, you can define your own function by making the logic of the `if` statement evaluate to `falsy`. In this case, to change the `if` statement logic to `falsy`, you need only to define your own `wp_parse_auth_cookie()` function before the `pluggable.php` file is loaded. I recommend defining the function in an [mu-plugin](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/must-use-plugins/).